# Entity Framework takes 30 minutes to generate a model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

No matter what I do, which DB I connect with, EF seems to take around 15-30 minutes to generate a model. While it's doing this, I get a "Visual Studio is busy" message in the system tray.

The first DB I connected to was complex and had a lot of data, lots of views so I thought, may be that's why. Now I have a local DB file with 1 table that has 2 columns and 3 rows. It still takes the same amount of time.

Eventually VS crashes and restarts. Has anyone had this problem before? Any idea?

---

I've looked at resource monitor, devenv.exe does not seem to be consuming any resources that would indicate it's doing a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a Visual Studio DVD in my DVD drive. Each time I did something with EF, VS started to read from the disc. I have no idea what or why, but the little LED would blink. Once I ejected the disk, everything ran fine. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

What credentials do you use to access your DB? Let's try ruling out domain latency issues first. If this is at work, can you verify the same flow on 2 separate machines using the same domain credentials? This wouldn't apply if you were using local creds.

Comment: The second DB that I'm using is a local DB on the same machine as VS. I have the same issue even if I try to add an empty model.